# PhpStorm + Xdebug + VMware VM = Time-out connecting to client

Tags: phpstorm, vmware, xdebug, remote-debugging

My Debian server (a VMware virtual machine) is up and running and all the settings in my PhpStorm are ok. I've set the virtual machine network adapter as bridged (also tried NAT).

My `xdebug.ini` looks like this:

```
zend_extension=xdebug.so
xdebug.profiler_enable=On
xdebug.remote_enable=On
xdebug.remote_host=MY_HOST_IP_ADDRESS
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_handler="dbgp"
xdebug.idekey=PHPSTORM
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
xdebug.remote_log="/tmp/xdebug.log"
```

Still, my `xdebug.log` looks pretty angry:

```
Log opened at 2018-07-01 14:54:08
I: Connecting to configured address/port: MY_HOST_IP_ADDRESS:9000.
E: Time-out connecting to client. :-(
Log closed at 2018-07-01 14:54:09
```

In fact, when I use telnet from my guest machine...

```
telnet MY_HOST_IP_ADDRESS 9000
Trying MY_HOST_IP_ADDRESS...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

I can't really get how to make this work after a couple of days. My SSH tunnel is also up and running (I've used the built in PhpStorm SSH tool), but even `netcat` doesn't help me out:

```
 nc MY_HOST_IP_ADDRESS 9000
 (UNKNOWN) [MY_HOST_IP_ADDRESS] 9000 (?) : Connection refused
```

This is my PhpStorm configuration (as you can see, the validation script looks good):

[image: Validation]
[image: CLI]
What am I missing?

Comment: What is `MY_HOST_IP_ADDRESS`? I understand -- you have masked the IP this way ... but what is running there/what machine is that?

Comment: That is the IP of my host machine, running the virtual machine. It's a Windows machine running my Debian VM server.

Comment: Where IDE is running? Same machine or another one?

Comment: Same machine. :)

Comment: 1) Firewall? Disable firewall for now .. or grant full access for PhpStorm. 2) Might be the wrong IP. It must be an IP as seen from within the virtual machine. Check `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` -- does it match the one you are trying to use? 3) Does PhpStorm listening for incoming xdebug connections? 4) Are you sure it's PhpStorm? Verify with `netstat`.

Comment: I've disabled the Firewall and checked that the IP is the same of  the one in `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`. Moreover, PhpStorm is listening for incoming Xdebug connections (phone like icon). I didn't get the meaning of point 4: may I ask for some insight, please?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174121/discussion-between-davide3i-and-lazyone).

Comment: 4) Maybe it's not PhpStorm who listens for Xdebug (but some another process). Netstat with appropriate params can tell what process is associated with endpoint. Since you are on Windows .. IDE shoudl detect that .. so unlikely to be the case. Are you able to connect to 9000 port using telnet from Windows host? It must be successful when IDE is listening and fail when not. maybe it's VM network restriction of some kind...?

Comment: Xdebug setup looks OK overall as long as correct IPs are used. But you are unable to connect via `telnet` and `nc` .. so it suggests network routing issue or firewall.

Comment: I wrote you in the chat.

Comment: Try to use `xdebug.remote_connect_back=1` instead of `xdebug.remote_host=MY_HOST_IP_ADDRESS`